# Including multiple messages in a Logstash output email

Tags: email, alert, logstash

Does anybody know a way to include multiple messages in the same email from Logstash?

Currently this is the configuration that I am using:

```
    if [LOGLEVEL] == "ERROR" AND [type] == "application" {
    email {
        from => "logstash@example.com"
        subject => "Application error on %{host}"
        to => "foo@example.com"
        via => "smtp"
        body => "%{message}"
        replyto => "bar@example.com"
    }
}
```

and it is sending emails, however what I'd like to be able to do is to send, say, the previous 20 messages from the same logfile, so that there is more information in the emails.  Is it possible to use a query as the body of the email?

If that's not possible has anyone been able to get the emails to send a link to a page or location in the Logstash server where more details can be found?

I'm using Logstash version 1.4.2 and have checked the documentation at http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/outputs/email but I can't see anything that might allow me to do what I'm trying to do.  I've also tried searching for examples of what I want on Google, but I can't find anything where people are including more information than what is in the current event.

Thanks,
Bill

Answer (score 1):

`message_format` would be help you

`if [LOGLEVEL] == "ERROR" AND [type] == "application" {
    email {
        from => "logstash@example.com"
        subject => "Application error on %{host}"
        to => "foo@example.com"
        via => "smtp"
        message_format => "%{mesage} yourlink, etc..."
        body => "%{message}"
        replyto => "bar@example.com"
    }
}`